# Admob Interstitial Ad not loading in Fragment in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to integrate Admob SmartBanner and Interstitial Ad in my app. SmartBanner is working fine but Interstitial Ads are not loading.

What is the proper code for integrating admob banner+Interstitial add in same app.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    final AdRequest.Builder request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
            .addTestDevice("1E085E6103A6876F42FC5183C73D98CB");//genymotion galaxy s5 4.4.4
    mAdView.loadAd(request.build());

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(String.valueOf(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));//("ca-app-pub-5059726881726792/4446999064");

    //final AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    //adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("1E085E6103A6876F42FC5183C73D98CB")//genymotion galaxy s5 4.4.4
    //        .addTestDevice("0B80CC732BD7E24CF42938649A17A7DA");//s3
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request.build());
        }
    });
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(request.build());
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you show the interstitial ad right after loading it.

There's always a latency(delay) issue with ads getting shown after requesting/loading them.

So you can't display your ad if it isn't loaded yet. Ideally, you should show interstitial ads at a natural break point in your app. Example: when transitioning from one activity to the other. However, you can modify your code to display the ad via the #onAdLoaded in your #onCreateView like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
```

Comment: It works for me with `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4`

Comment: The check `if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())` seems to be redundant, as this callback method is called only after ad has indeed already been loaded.